# Add value to column in database via the rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I have a table in my database called "users". In this table, I have 4 columns: Firstname, Lastname, Age, Location (all created with the usual: `rails generate migration add_firstname_to_users firstname:string`).

If I have an existing user with the columns FirstName, Lastname, and Age already populated but Location is empty, how can I add a value to Location for a specific user via the rails console? Been googling all day, cant seem to find an answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Open rails console: `rails console` (in short `rails c`)
- Find specific user:  `user = User.find 1` # Note here '1' is specific user ID

And then,

```
user.location = "location value"
user.save! # Force to raise errors if any validation fails
```

OR

`user.update_attribute(:location, "location value")`